# Find value and index in panda series where the value increased 5 times

Tags: python, pandas, series

In a panda series it should go through the series and stop if one value has increased 5 times. With a simple example it works so far:

```
list2 = pd.Series([2,3,3,4,5,1,4,6,7,8,9,10,2,3,2,3,2,3,4])

def cut(x):
    y = iter(x)
    for i in y:
        if x[i] < x[i+1] < x[i+2] < x[i+3] < x[i+4] < x[i+5]:
            return x[i]
            break

out = cut(list2)

index = list2[list2 == out].index[0]
```

So I get the correct Output of 1 and Index of 5.

But if I use a second list with series type and instead of (19,) which has (23999,) values then I get the Error:

```
pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item

KeyError: 3489660928
```

Comment: You're indexing the series on indices that do not exist in the last positions. For instance on `i = len(df)`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
# compare list2 with the previous values
s = list2.gt(list2.shift()) 

# looking at last 5 values
s = s.rolling(5).sum()

# select those equal 5
list2[s.eq(5)]
```

Output:

```
10     9
11    10
dtype: int64
```

The first index where it happens is

```
s.eq(5).idxmax()
# output 10
```

Also, you can chain them together:

```
(list2.gt(list2.shift())
      .rolling(5).sum()
      .eq(5).idxmax()
)
```

Comment: Did you mean `idxmin`?